# Best practice to retrieve Json value stored in sql table through c# code

Tags: sql, json, .net, class, entity

I have a JSON value stored in SQL Server. I want to retrieve that JSON value and bind it to C# property (which is deserialized to desired entity). I want to know what would be the best practice to do that effectively? Right now, I'm doing like this:

```
Public class Employee
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
}

Public class EmployeeData
{
    public string JsonEmployeeText {get;set;} // Binding the json string from database    
    public List<Employee> Employees { get { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(JsonEmployeeText );}} //Converting the retrieved json string from Database to c# entity
}
```

Comment: I've fixed the code formatting in your post. But you have `Public` with a capital `P`. The `public` keyword in C# is written in all lower-case, does your code really have it with a capital `P`? I didn't change it just in case that's part of the problem, but...

Comment: T.J. Crowder Thanks for looking into it. This is sample code posted to explain my logic. That's it. I will have my correct code once i figure out the logic and method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we should not do any sort of database logic on getters as it can sometimes delay the process of initialization in case we need to use this we need to make sure we enable the lazy loading